# XSLT: Split second level root element into two of an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Need an xslt to convert the below input to the mentioned output.
Basically need to split the second level element into two nodes. Few nodes from the inner most needs to be moved to a spearate node altogether, and the second level node  needs to be renamed as well.

**Input:**

```
    <Root>
    <Root2>
    <Node1>
      <Node1_1></Node1_1>
      <Node1_2></Node1_2>
      <Node1_3></Node1_3>
    </Node1>

    <Node2>
      <Node2_1></Node2_1>
      <Node2_2></Node2_2>
      <Node2_3></Node2_3>
    </Node2>

    <Node3>
      <Node3_1></Node3_1>
      <Node3_2></Node3_2>
      <Node3_3></Node3_3>
    </Node3>
  </Root2>
     </Root>
```

**Output:**

```
    <Root>
  <NewRoot2>
    <Node1_1></Node1_1>
    <Node1_2></Node1_2>
  </NewRoot2>
  <NewRoot3>
    <Node1_3></Node1_3>
    <Node2_1></Node2_1>
    <Node2_2></Node2_2>
    <Node2_3></Node2_3>
    <Node3_1></Node3_1>
    <Node3_2></Node3_2>
    <Node3_3></Node3_3>
  </NewRoot3>
    </Root>
```

Comment: I don't see any rhyme or reason to your output and I don't think you've explained it. What determines that 1_1 and 1_2 are in `NewRoot2` and the rest in `NewRoot3`. What determines that `NewRoot2` is numbered starting at 2?

Comment: 1_2 and 1_2 are under NewRoot2 because, that the how the destination application accepts it. :( I have to sent my XML to the destination service in a specific way it needs,so i am transforming it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

To the delivered input en the desired output you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <Root>
            <NewRoot2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node1_1|//Node1_2" />
            </NewRoot2>
            <NewRoot3>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node1_3|//Node2/*|//Node3/*" />
            </NewRoot3>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```